# My sql statement does not like my partion over statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have this simple query in DB2. I'm getting an error at the 2nd line from the top. For someone reason, it does not want to run my over(partition) line?

```
with core as(
select  *,row_number() over(partition by asgnd_to_pin order by stdt asc) as rank
from mhal_rep.stushh
where stus_cd in ('DWRT', 'FINL', 'DWFL', 'DWR', 'DWSR', 'DWPC')
AND STDT BETWEEN '2009-02-28' AND '2019-02-28'
UNION
select  *,row_number() over(partition by asgnd_to_pin order by stdt asc) as rank
from mhal_rep.stusha
where stus_cd in ('DWRT', 'FINL', 'DWFL', 'DWR', 'DWSR', 'DWPC')
AND STDT BETWEEN '2009-02-28' AND '2019-02-28'
 ),

 core1 as(
select asgnd_to_pin, stus_cd, stdt, rank, (('2019-02-28'-stdt)/365) as     
lngth_srvc
from core
where rank=1 and 
asgnd_to_pin in (
'788387',
'271562',
'155851')

select *
from core 1;
```

The error I'm getting says:

```
ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2] SQL0104N An unexpected token "," was found    
following "". Expected tokens may include: "FROM INTO".
```

Comment: Any idea why my lngth_srvc calculation is off. For instance, when stdt=11/03/2010, it is saying lngth_srvc = 220.068. There are not 220 years between 2019-02-28 and 11/03/2010. I tried "Date('2019-02-28') - Date(stdt)" and the result is still wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
select  t.*, row_number() over(partition by asgnd_to_pin order by stdt asc) as rank
from mhal_rep.stushX t
...
```

instead of

```
select  *, row_number() over(partition by asgnd_to_pin order by stdt asc) as rank
from mhal_rep.stushX
...
```

But actually you have more problems:
- `core1` subselect is not closed by `)`
- space between `core` and `1` in the outer select statement

Answer (score 0):

just remove space between core and 1

```
select *
from core1;
```